# Unexpected preg_replace results

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Greetigns,

I am currently trying to replace an html tag with "" and I can't seem to get this expression to work.

Sample Data:

```
    </span><span class="ni2y">209</span>.<span
```

Expected Output:

```
    </span>.<span
```

Preg Replace:

```
    $pLineTemp = '</span><span class="ni2y">209</span>.<span';
    $pClassName = 'ni2y';
    $pClassReplace = "(.span class.." . $pClassName . "..\\d+..span.)";
    $pLineTemp = preg_replace($pClassReplace, '', $pLineTemp);
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: hrmm, that code seems to work like that, let me see whats going on here and why its not working in my loop.

Comment: Do you need two slashes in front of the d for a number? I thought it was `\d+`?

Comment: n/m, issue was with how I was building my result string, I needed to take it out of the loop, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n/m, issue was with how I was building my result string, I needed to take it out of the loop, thanks!